# How do I access / create a GQL type resolver with AWS Lambda?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am working with a new codebase. They are using GraphQL and deploying it to AWS AppSync. I have a typical `.graphql` file with all of my GQL types defined.

```
type Query {
    getUser(id: String!): User
    ....
}

type Mutation {
    updateUser(....): User
    .... 
}

type User {
    id: String!
    name: String
}

... Other stuff
```

My resolvers all go through a handler file with a case statement for each query / mutation.

```
const hander = async (event) => {
    switch(event.info.fieldName) {
        case 'getUser': // do stuff
        .... other case statements
    }
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to add other non scalar fields to the `User` and in the process how to create a resolver for those fields. For example, if I wanted to add a `posts: [Post]` to the user and needed to do some logic to get those posts, where would it be added.

The handler only takes in the query or mutation (as far as I can tell). Where should the other resolvers be and how are they accessed?

I have googled and looked through the AWS docs, but can't find what I am looking for (although this has always been a very basic part of my GQL experience), so I am assuming they have a different paradigm that I just don't understand.

Any help / links would be great.